ASP.NET Core/IIS: "HTTP Error 404.8 - Not Found" – Why is the web.config file dealt differently with than other content root files?
I set-up an ASP.NET Core app to be hosted in-process by IIS.
When I try to access any file from the content root folder, a HTTP 404 is correctly returned by Kestrel.
However, when I request https://localhost/web.config, I'm getting the following HTTP error message:
HTTP Error 404.8 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a path in the URL that contains a hiddenSegment section.

I want to receive a generic HTTP 404 for this file, too. Attackers shouldn't be able to sniff the technolocy I'm using.
What would need to be changed?

Since HTTP error pages can come from your web framework (ASP.NET Core) as well as IIS (request filtering module), such differences are unavoidable. You can override such error pages with your own, https://learn.microsoft.com/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/

There are two things that can happen when the httpError module encounters an error:

A custom error is generated
A detailed error is generated

Many HTTP errors have a sub-status. The IIS default Custom Errors configuration does not differentiate based sub-status codes. Even though error 404.8 should be displayed, but it still sends the Custom Error page(404). Follow the steps below to accomplish this

Open the IIS server, and click Error Pages.



Choose 404 and click the Edit Feature Settings



Tick on Custom error pages


You can learn more form this Microsoft document

I think the issue is more complex: All other files are forwarded to Kestrel, which in turn returns an empty body 404 response. However, wenn I call //localhost/web.config, an IIS error page is generated, regardless of the suggested setting. — If I remove the web.config filters from the *Request Filtering section, IIS throws and displays an internal error "Invalid empty XML file".

Before: https://i.sstatic.net/jy23y8ZF.png and After: https://i.sstatic.net/nyh5KUPN.png
It works on me.  And  DetailedLocalOnly (default) is also a errorMode which means that Custom Errors are generated for every remote request but Detailed for local.

Yes, but that's only for the web.config file. See the difference in the result for any other file: https://i.sstatic.net/zOEmMpR5.png

I understand what you mean.  web.config contains sensitive configuration. So request filtering module is configured to deny access to specific files or directories, including web.config.  To make it show a generic 404 error by not protecting web.config,  this is actually an insecure operation. This is completely contrary to your original intention.

You can also learn more about security consideration in error messages.

Yes, I know. Well, I believe, the answer to my question is to create an empty 404 custom error page and have that being returned when web.config is called. So, on the surface, it will look like any other missing content to the user.

Nonetheless, this discussion was very helpful for me. Thank you!

I'm glad you got it to work.
